# Find the product of all values of $(1+i\sqrt 3)^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

Find the product of all values of $(1+i\sqrt 3)^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

**My try:**

$(1+i\sqrt 3)^{\frac{3}{4}}=\exp (\frac{3}{4}(Log(1+i\sqrt 3)))=\exp(\frac{3}{4}(\log2+i\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi i))$.

I am kinda stuck on how to find the product of all values of  the above expression.
Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+i\sqrt3=2e^{i\pi/3}$$
The fourth roots of this number have common magnitude $2^{1/4}$ and arguments $\pi/12,7\pi/12,-5\pi/12,-11\pi/12$. The $\frac34$-powers thus have common magnitude $2^{3/4}$ and arguments $\pi/4,7\pi/4\equiv-\pi/4,-5\pi/4\equiv3\pi/4,-11\pi/4\equiv-3\pi/4$. The producf of all the four possible values of $(1+i\sqrt3)^{3/4}$ therefore has magnitude equal to the product of the magnitudes of each possible value, which is $8$, and argument equal to the sum of the arguments of each possible value, which is $0$. The final answer is $8$.

Comment: I am stuck at how you found that there are $4$ arguements, Wont there be $n$ arguments?

Comment: @Math_Freak $n=4$ here. A rational $p/q$-th root of a complex number (where the fraction is lowest-terms) has $q$ possible values.

Comment: We need product of the values of $(2e^{i\frac\pi3})^\frac34$. Since there will be four values, can we say the answer would be  $((2e^{i\frac\pi3})^\frac34)^4=8e^{i\pi}=-8?$